# multiple find and replace in php

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have a string like the one below

```
$str="<444970836741>BOA LTD.                                              
  CR
      9,00,000.00         Not Available           Not Available    Not Available           Not Available    TBI   31/12/13    31/12/13";
```

and I need the output as below

```
444970836741,900000.00,31/12/13,31/12/13
```

I need to do the following

1. Remove '<' and '>'
2. Remove TBI
3. Remove 'Not Available' field
4. preserve `sn` (i.e 444970836741)
5. preserve amount but remove comma from amount(900000.00)
6. preserve start date and end date (both 31/12/13) 6.

I tried with `str_replace` but it is really painful to remove all whitespaces and unnecessary characters. Can it be done in PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014089/regular-expression-to-consider-periods-after-numeric-character-only-in-php

Answer (score 1):

[`strcspn`](http://php.net/strcspn), [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) and [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) can help you

```
$str = "<444970836741>BOA LTD.                                              
  CR
      9,00,000.00         Not Available           Not Available    Not Available           Not Available    TBI   31/12/13    31/12/13"; 

function complicated($string)
{
    // Change into array
    $array = explode(" ", $string);

    // Unset element has no numbers
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(strcspn($value, '0123456789') == strlen($value)){
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }

    // Return all the values of an array
    $array = array_values($array);

    // Remove everything from a string but just numbers
    $array[0] = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$array[0]);

    // Remove commas
    $array[1] = str_replace(',', '', $array[1]);

    // Return
    return implode(',', $array);
}

echo complicated($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with array condition. See "$search" description for this function:

The value being searched for, otherwise known as the needle. An array may be used to designate multiple needles.

```
$str = str_replace(array('<', '>', 'TBI', 'Not Available', ','), '', $str);
```

And, for remove all double whitespaces, use [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);
```