# regular expression to consider periods after numeric character only in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following code

```
<?php
$str="$str="115(JOHN DOE.)      900,000.00 SALARY.    45 AGE.   "; 
$str=preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z(),]/", "", $str);          
echo $str=preg_replace('!\s+!', ',', $str);
?>
```

This output

```
115,.,900000.00.,45.,
```

but this is not exactly what i need, i need to consider period which is inside 900,000.00 and ignore that of JOHN DOE. , SALARY.,AGE.

How can i do that to get

```
115,900000.00,45
```

I.e i need regular expression to consider periods after numeric character only

Comment: Is the string fixed size?

Comment: Will the stuff you want to remove always be between parentheses?

Comment: My answer takes your edit into consideration :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without trying to improve your code...this should do it:

```
$str="115(JOHN DOE.)      900,000.00(SALARY.)    45(AGE.)";
$str=preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z]+\.+/", "", $str);
$str=preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z(),]/", "", $str);
echo $str=preg_replace('!\s+!', ',', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it in three steps:

```
$a = "115(JOHN DOE.)      900,000.00(SALARY.)";
$a = preg_replace("/\([A-Z ]*\.\)/", "", $a);          // 115      900,000.00
$b = preg_replace("/,/", "", $a);                     // 115      900000.00
$c = preg_replace("/\s+/", ",", $b);                  // 115,900000.00
```

You can change this line:

```
$a = preg_replace("/\([A-Z ]*\.\)/", "", $a);
```

with this:

```
$a = preg_replace("/[A-Z ]*\./", "", $a);
```

to remove data without parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '115(JOHN DOE.)      900,000.00 SALARY.    45 AGE. ';
preg_match_all("/\d+(?:(?:[,.]\d+)+)?/", $str, $match);
$match = array_map(function($val) { return str_replace(",", "", $val); }, $match[0]);
echo implode(",", $match);
```

**Output**:

```
115,900000.00,45
```